# Question 116391 is closed as "not a real question", what do I need to add?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen

Question 116391, [Mouse grips: How much will I benefit from using a claw or fingertip grip over a palm grip, and is it worth the additional fatigue?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116391/what-are-the-differences-between-the-palm-claw-and-fingertip-mouse-grip-styles), has been closed as *not a real question*, despite my efforts to make the question more specific.  What do I need to add to the question to allow for it to be reopened?

Comment: You voted to close your own question?

Comment: Yeah, lol--I felt like I was under pressure to close it.

Comment: I'm not sure how objective you can be with what you're looking for.  I'm also not sure how mouse grips relate to gaming.  It sounds sort of like you're trying to shoehorn it into a gaming context.  Unless I'm missing something about it.

Comment: Mouse grip styles are in fact a gaming topic, see http://www.razerzone.com/mouseguide/ergonomic

Comment: Reading that page, it sounds like you're seeding the question, as your original question is answered with that.  As to what it is now, I don't think there are (or can be) metrics for each grip style.  Each person is different, and will be better with their own style.  In any case, I don't think Razer catering to different grip styles makes mouse grips related to gaming.

Comment: Pretty much every professional gamer uses a fingertip grip. So even though your question was closed, there's your answer.

Comment: @Decency: Do you have evidence for this statement? The Razer page linked above seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @DragonLord Huh? I fail to see how stating the obvious- that a company wants to sell its product- is ranting, but sure, we can go with that.

Comment: @Decency: Sorry for the mistake--but please avoid using profanity in the future, as your comments could be read as offensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your latest revision reads:

> I've been reading about several different ways to use a mouse for gaming, including palm, claw, and fingertip grips. I understand that the claw and fingertip grips allow for more precise movement and faster button presses than the palm grip, but how much of a difference in game-play performance can I expect, as measured by K/D ratios or other similar metrics? Is this worth the additional fatigue?

This isn't something that can be objectively measured at all.  There's nothing that says, "Palm grip will double your K/D ratio".  Each person is different, and will act differently with different grips.

For example, I'm pretty good at super-clicking, but I suck at precision while doing so.  In order to compensate, I hold down the mouse with my left hand, and mash that click for all I'm worth with my right; does that mean I'm better with a claw grip?  Or a fingertip grip?  I dunno.

It's a very individual metric, and I don't think it's one we can put an objective value on.

Maybe closing it as Not A Real Question wasn't the correct reason; it should be Not Constructive, as I don't think there's any expertise we can use to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Everything below the "Edit" mark is a good question that sounds like an expert asking other experts for advice. It doesn't need anything added at this point – it needs the original "let me google that for you" seeding question above the edit mark removed and a title edit to describe the remaining problem.

Comment: Original question edited.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116391/how-much-will-i-benefit-from-using-a-claw-or-fingertip-mouse-grip-over-a-palm-gr